# SilverStripe Functional Testing: asserting the ajax content by selector

Tags: silverstripe, functional-testing, silverstripe-4

I am working on a SilverStripe project. I am writing functional tests for my project. Now I am having a problem asserting the Ajax content or content within the Vue JS or React JS component using assertExactMatchBySelector or assertPartialHTMLMatchBySelector or assertPartialMatchBySelector.

I am rendering a Vue JS component or React JS component in my template as follows.

```
<div id="content">
      <form-component></form-component>
</div>
```

Then within the JS component class, I have a heading.

```
<h1 id="testing">I am heading</h1>
```

Then I am writing a functional test to ensure that the heading is rendered with the right text.

```
    $this->get($page->URLSegment);
    $this->assertExactMatchBySelector('#testing', [
        'I am heading'
    ]);
```

When I run my test, the test is failing. It is failing probably because the Vue JS or React JS component code are like Ajax content. That is why. How can I assert it?

Comment: I don't think FunctionalTest will help for Vue or React driven pages. You'll need to use Behat for that.

Comment: OK Thanks @RobbieAverill.